# Deleting a job still shows the job in queue in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

```
job_id = BulkUploadWorker.perform_async(params)
    session[:job_id] =  job_id
```

This is how i am saving the job_id in session. When I removed the job from the queue

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new
    queue.each do |job|
      if job.jid ==  session[:job_id]
         job_removed=job.delete

      end
    end
```

Up to here there is no problem. Now when i check its status

```
ap Sidekiq::Status::status(session[:job_id])
```

I get `:queued`

To get it working again, I have to run this command in rails console

`Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.flushdb }`

Any idea why this is happening?

### Edit 1

I am using a gem called `sidekiq-status` to get the status of the process. In my `rails c` when i ran `sidekiq::Queue.new.find_job('jid')` I got nil after deleting it. I guess the issue is with sidekiq-status gem?